# how to check single values in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

here is my problem. Assume I have csv file and when I import it by pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
csv_file = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv', header=0).set_index(['npk']).reset_index()   
print(csv_file)
```

I will get this result:

```
   npk one  two  three
0    1  S1    2      3
1    2  S2    5      6
2    3  S3    8      9
```

Also I have some parameters in another csv file. When I import them like this:

```
par = {}
b = {}
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('settings.csv'))
for row in csv_reader:
    key = row[1]
    value1 = int(row[2])
    value2 = int(row[3])
    value3 = int(row[4])
    value4 = int(row[5])
    value5 = int(row[6])
    b = {key: [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5]}
    par.update(b)

print(par)
```

I will get this library as result:

```
{'S1': [4, -20, 20, 0, 0], 'S2': [6, -20, 20, -10, 10], 'S3': [10, -20, 20, -10, 10]}
```

Now I would like to check each row in first table and take column `one` and compare if that column == to according key in library, e.g. `== 'S1'`, then do something with column `two` e.g. multiply with 2, if it `== 'S2'`, then multiply by 3, if it `== 'S3'` then multiply by 4, and make new column e.g. `result` as a result. I cannot figure out how can I turn to each row in dataframe, check value in corresponding row, compare it with another parameter and then do something with another column and make a result in additional column. Would you please help me with it? Thank you!

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want to do?

Comment: If in dataframe table column `one` value equals to library key, e.g. `S1`, then take from dataframe table value from column `two` and compare with library `S1` first value, e.g. `4`. If it is bigger, then do something, else do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
def calculation(row):
    value = par[row["one"]][0]
    if row["two"] > value:
        row["two"] += 1
    else:
        row["two"] -= 1
    
csv_file = csv_file.apply(calculation, axis = 1)
```